# How to remove specific characters from large set of data

Tags: vba, excel

I am cleaning a large set of data full of symbol characters ex. `!@%^&*|'~<>?·` and want to remove them all at one time. The script below seems to do so effectively, however it then goes on to delete the entire contents of the workbook.

```
Sub Removeforeigncharacters()
  Dim ForeignChars As String
  Dim RegChars As String

  ForeignChars = "!@%^&*|`~<>?·"
  RegChars = ""
  Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

  Dim A As String * 1
  Dim B As String * 1
  Dim i As Integer

  For i = 1 To Len(ForeignChars)
    A = Mid(ForeignChars, i, 1)
    B = Mid(RegChars, i, 1)
    MyRange.Replace What:=A, Replacement:=B, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You are using * would be my guess maybe.  Do you know where in the loop this happens, isolate the char that's causing it

Comment: What does the `*` do here, `Dim A As String * 1`?  Also, when you get to the `*`, you want to find/replace `~*`.

Comment: I removed the asterisks and it still deletes the entire sheet. I do not know where in the loop this happens - i am not too skillful in vba

Comment: @BruceWayne - it's a [fixed length string](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/3418/data-types-and-limits/11784/string#t=201701032053010822684).

Comment: 1 Major Issue I see with this is the "!" being in a foreign character.  I know that excel freaks out when I try to remove it, without it being part of more characters.  Additionally, the apostrophe, in my past, has began removing entire cells worth of data... not sure why, but I've had that issue as well.  Possibly if you made a replace function for each individual item, you can figure out the problem children, then combine later?

Comment: If your `Replace` is being done with `LookAt:=xlFormulas`, then changing something like `=IF('Sheet 5'!A4<>'Another Sheet'!B6,D7*17,59)` to `=IF(Sheet 5A4Another SheetB6,D717,59)` is going to cause real problems.  If your worksheet **only** has values, you should be OK.  (Apart from the issues with wildcard and other special characters.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must **escape** your problems:

```
Sub Removeforeigncharacters()
  Dim ForeignChars As String
  Dim RegChars As String

  ForeignChars = "!@%^&|`~<>·"
  RegChars = ""
  Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

  Dim A As String * 1
  Dim B As String * 1
  Dim i As Integer

  For i = 1 To Len(ForeignChars)
    A = Mid(ForeignChars, i, 1)
    B = Mid(RegChars, i, 1)

    MyRange.Replace What:=A, Replacement:=B, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
  Next

  MyRange.Replace What:="~*", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
  MyRange.Replace What:="~`", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
  MyRange.Replace What:="~?", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
  MyRange.Replace What:="~~", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
End Sub
```

Note I have reduced `ForeignChars`

Comment: @YowE3K I will fix it

Comment: P.S.  I love your first sentence!

Comment: You still have the backtick in `ForeignChars`.  (I don't use wildcards in `Find` often enough / at all, so I don't know whether a backtick actually is a special case or not.  All I know is that it **looks** strange being treated both ways.)

Answer (score 5):

The `What` parameter of `Range.Replace` uses `*` as a wildcard, which means that it will match every single character (and them replace them).  Note that this doesn't technically *remove* the characters because you're using fixed length strings - it replaces them with spaces because the code...

```
B = Mid(RegChars, i, 1)
```

...is always going to result in a space.

If you need to search for the literal `*` instead of the wildcard match, you need to escape them:

```
  Dim A As String
  Dim i As Integer

  For i = 1 To Len(ForeignChars)
    A = Mid(ForeignChars, i, 1)
    If A Like "[~*?`]" Then A = "~" & A
    MyRange.Replace What:=A, Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
  Next
```

(I may have missed some that need escaping).

Note that if you do this, you can't declare `A` as a fixed length string (there really isn't a compelling reason to do that anyway).

Answer (score 2):

Using an array should give you a significant performance boost.

Here is how:

- Load the data into an array
- Test each element to see if it contains ant of the Foreign Characters

  - Remove the Foreign Characters
- Write the data back to the WorkSheet

---

```
Sub Removeforeigncharacters()
    Dim x As Long, y As Long
    Dim Data As Variant, ForeignChars As Variant, v As Variant

    ForeignChars = "!@%^&*|`~<>?·"
    Data = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value2

    For x = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        For y = 1 To UBound(Data, y)
            For Each v In ForeignChars
                If InStr(Data(x, y), v) Then
                    Data(x, y) = Replace(Data(x, y), v, "")
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value2 = Data

End Sub
```